# rpmbuild error: Symlink points to BuildRoot

Tags: rpm

In the package that I'm building, there are symbolic links within the Buildroot directory. For instance this:

```
 /home/sg/impkg/buildroot/dir1/bin/w_be -> /home/sg/impkg/buildroot/dir2/targ/be
```

This is making `rpmbuild` to fail with the error:

```
 RPM build errors:
 Symlink points to BuildRoot: 
 /home/sg/impkg/buildroot/dir1/bin/w_be -> /home/sg/impkg/buildroot/dir2/targ/be
```

In my `%files` section, I have only included the `buildroot` directory, which is what I want. Following is a snippet from my spec-file:

```
Summary:                research compiler tool set
License:                GPL
Name:                   %{name}
Version:                %{version}
Release:                %{release}
Source:                 %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Prefix:                 /usr
Group:                  Development/Tools
Autoreq:                0
Autoprov:               0

%description
research compiler tool set

%prep
%setup -q

%build
rm -rf %{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version}
mkdir %{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version}
cd %{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version} && %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/./configure --     prefix=%{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version}
make %{?_smp_mflags} -C %{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version}

%install
cd %{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version} && make DESTDIR=%{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version}  install

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}/%{name}-%{version}

%files
%defattr(755,-,-)
/%{name}-%{version}
```

I have to adhere to the logic, which means I cannot remove these links from the Makefiles...how do I solve this problem and generate the RPM?

Answer (score 3):

Symlinks *must* be relative so that the package will work when installed. Patch the makefile to fix this.